# MySQL join on multiple columns (all containing the same range of integers)

Tags: php, mysql, join, select, sql-view

I have a view (in phpmyadmin) with a number of attributes ranked from 1-73 for various football (soccer) teams

[image: team_attribute_rank]

And another with an equivalent text description to include as part of a descriptive output string.

[image: equivalent text]

I am trying to produce a MySql view identical to the first image, but containing the text descriptions instead of the numbers in the cells.

I have tried a left join from the first table, and can do this succesfully for individual columns, however I cannot do it for more than one column at a time.

Can anyone assist?  The text will be output onto a webpage via PHP, JAVA, HTML & CSS.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Show parts you did. Explain re being stuck. Clearly & concisely  phrase & research that problem before considering asking.

Answer (score 1):

You would typically join the description table once per column in the view. Each join uses a different alias, so it is not ambiguous. You can then refer to the description in the `where` clause.

Assuming that your view is called `myview`  and that the description table is called `descr`, that would be:

```
select
    v.team_name,
    d_finishing.description finishing,
    d_long_shots.description long_shots,
    d_pace.description pace,
    ...
from myview v
inner join descr d_finishing on d_finishing.rank = t.finishing
inner join descr d_long_shots on d_long_shots.rank = t.long_shots
inner join descr d_pace on d_pace.rank = t.pace
inner join ...
```

You could also do this with a series of correlated subqueries:

```
select
    v.team_name,
    (select description from descr d where d.rank = t.finishing) finishing,
    (select description from descr d where d.rank = t.long_shots) long_shots,
    (select description from descr d where d.rank = t.pace) pace,
    ...
from myview v
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was racking my brains for ages trying to figure that out.